# ssl different behavior between nginx on Ubuntu and nginx on Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, nginx

I use same version(1.5.0) nginx on both Ubuntu and windows. The two nginx server work as reverse proxy in front of glassfish2.x. The glassfish2.x enables https listener, and my nginx servers have ssl certificate files too. My nginx on Ubuntu works fine but that one on windows doesn't. The app on GlassFish says that the user name and password are wrong when logging into the app via https through nginx.
The configurations of two nginx on Ubuntu and Windows are same.

```
    server {

  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name 127.0.0.1;

  ssl_certificate server.crt;

  ssl_certificate_key server.key;


  location / {

    proxy_pass https://10.112.18.110;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

  }

}
```

I found the TLS versions are different from Chrome, the nginx on Ubuntu uses tlsv1.1 and ACE_256_CBC, but the nginx on windows uses tlsv1.0 and AES_128_cbc. I don't know how to make the nginx on windows use tlsv1.1. If I could do this, I will test them again to see the nginx on windows works or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's my bad. I found one app was installed on my local machine(windows) before and was launched automatically as windows service. This app is listening the 443 port number. When my Nginx on windows starts, it doesn't report error because 80 port number is not used by other process. When accessing the local site using HTTPS, it just talks to the app on my local machine instead of my nginx.
I shutdown the app and retest nginx on windows, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Because the error is reported by the application server, this means that the SSL tunnel was established. You should search for your problem somewhere else.

You can use a HTTP debugging proxy like Fiddler to see the encrypted HTTPS conversation. Compare the Fiddler log from both Nginx servers.